# Python pytorch function consumes memory excessively quickly

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, pytorch, ram

I am writing a function with pytorch that feeds inputs through a transformer model, then condenses the last embedding layer by computing the average along a specific axis (using a subset of indices defined by a mask). Since the output of the model is very very large, I need to process the inputs in batches.

My question does not concern the logic of this function as I believe I have the correct implementation. My issue is that the function I wrote consumes memory excessively quickly and practically makes it unusable.

Here is my function:

```
def get_chunk_embeddings(encoded_dataset, batch_size):
  chunk_embeddings = torch.empty([0,768])
  for i in range(len(encoded_dataset['input_ids'])//batch_size):
    input_ids = encoded_dataset['input_ids'][i*batch_size:i*batch_size + batch_size]
    attention_mask = encoded_dataset['attention_mask'][i*batch_size:i*batch_size + batch_size]
    embeddings = model.forward(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)['last_hidden_state']
    embeddings = embeddings * attention_mask[:,:,None]
    embeddings = embeddings.sum(dim=1)/attention_mask.sum(dim=1)[:,None]
    chunk_embeddings = torch.cat([chunk_embeddings, embeddings],0)
  return chunk_embeddings
```

Now let's talk memory (the numbers below assume that I pass a batch_size of 8):

- I am using google colab and I have ~25 GB of RAM available
- The `model` is a BERT model and consumes 413 MB
- `encoded_dataset` consumes 0.48 GB
- `input_ids` consumes 0.413 MB
- `attention_mask` consumes 4.096 KB
- `embeddings` at its peak consumption consume 12.6 MB
- `chunk_embeddings` adds 0.024576 MB with each iteration

So from my understanding, I should be able to allow `chunk_embeddings` to grow up to: 25GB - 413MB - 0.48GB - 0.413MB - 4.096KB - 12.6MB ~= 24 GB. Enough for almost 1 million iterations..

Here I will walk through an example of what I am experiencing:

1. Before running my function, google colab tells me that I have plenty of memory

[image]

2. Now, for the sake of example, I will run the function (for only 3 iterations)
   To be explicit, I put this at the end of my for loop:
   `if (i == 2):return chunk_embeddings`
3. Now I run the code `val = get_chunk_embeddings(train_encoded_dataset, 8)`
   So even with just 3 iterations, somehow I consume almost 5.5 GB of RAM.

[image]

Why is this happening? Also after I have returned from the function all of the local variables should be deleted and there is no way that `val` is so large.

Could someone tell me what it is I am doing wrong or am not understanding? Please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: Is your ```return chunk_embeddings``` supposed to be within the for loop?

Comment: sorry nice catch. it should not be. I edited it

Comment: Do you need to backprop from `chunk_embeddings`  later? Currently, when you `cat` the `embeddings` in each iteration, the entire computational graph of each forward pass will be preserved to allow this. If you do not, then you could call `detach()` on `embeddings`  before the `cat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon @GoodDeeds' answer, by default the computations within a `pytorch.nn` module (model) create the computation graph and preserve the gradient (unless you are using `with torch.no_grad()` or something similar. That means that at every iteration of your loop, the computational graph for embeddings is stored within the tensor `embeddings`. `embeddings.grad` is likely much larger than `embeddings` itself because the gradient of each layer value with respect to each previous layer's value is maintained. Next, since you use `torch.cat`, you append `embeddingsd` and the associated gradient to `chunk_embeddings`. That means that after a few iterations, `chunk_embeddings` stores a huge number of gradient values, which is where your memory is going. There are a few solutions:

1. If you need to use chunk embeddings for backpropogation (i.e. training), you should move your loss calculation and optimizer step within the loop, such that the gradients are automatically cleared afterwards.
2. If this function is only used during inference, you can disable the gradient computation entirely (which should also speed computation slightly) using `torch.no_grad()`, or you can use `torch.detach()` on `embeddings` at each iteration as suggested in the comments.

Example:

```
def get_chunk_embeddings(encoded_dataset, batch_size):
  with torch.no_grad():
    chunk_embeddings = torch.empty([0,768])
    for i in range(len(encoded_dataset['input_ids'])//batch_size):
      input_ids = encoded_dataset['input_ids'][i*batch_size:i*batch_size + batch_size]
      attention_mask = encoded_dataset['attention_mask'][i*batch_size:i*batch_size + batch_size]
      embeddings = model.forward(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)['last_hidden_state']
      embeddings = embeddings * attention_mask[:,:,None]
      embeddings = embeddings.sum(dim=1)/attention_mask.sum(dim=1)[:,None]
      chunk_embeddings = torch.cat([chunk_embeddings, embeddings],0)
  return chunk_embeddings
```